# SQLite Query in Python returns empty results

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have to download a database file and decompress it and query using SQLite query in python. 
Location of the file:

http://amazonlinux.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2/core/2.0/x86_64/11be506f86779fba9940dfce8be18d996726d1db2267fd3b13585c19e638db48/repodata/primary.sqlite.gz

For some strange reason the below code returns empty results if the run this code on remote database (primary.sqlite) , unlike if I run the same code to a custom created database with similar values.

The below code returns all the values between two version ranges if the 
upper limit of the version given is greater the the max value of the version in the table.

```
Customdb.db :

create table packages(version varchar,name varchar);


insert into packages values('7.61.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.51.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.51.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.51.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.51.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.51.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.61.1',"libcurl");
```

Query:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Customdb.db')

c = conn.cursor()

software_name = "libcurl"
v1_start = "0.0.0"
v2_end_inc = "24.12.1"
v2_end_ex = "24.12.1"
only_version = '20.61.1'
print (type(v2_end_inc))

c.execute("""
        select name,version from packages
        where name = ?1 and
        1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000
        between
        (1000000 * replace(?2, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(?2, instr(?2, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(?2, '.', '000') % 1000)
        and
        (1000000 * replace(?3, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(?3, instr(?3, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(?3, '.', '000') % 1000)
        and
        (SELECT 1000000 * replace(?3, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(?3, instr(?3, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(?3, '.', '000') % 1000) >=
        (SELECT MAX(1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 ) FROM packages)
        ORDER BY
        (1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000)
    """, (software_name, v1_start, v2_end_inc))
```

Results:

```
libcurl|7.51.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.51.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.51.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.51.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.51.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.61.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.61.1
```

If I download the file and decompress it and run the simple code it returns these results so there is nothing wrong with the downloading the remote file and decompressing it.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('primary.sqlite')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT version FROM packages where name = 'libcurl' ")

results = c.fetchall()

package_obj_list = []  
l = len(results)
for package in results:
   package_obj_list.append(package)

print (package_obj_list)

results are:

[ [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  “7.61.1” ], [  “7.61.1” ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  “7.61.1” ]]
```

The below code returns all the values between two version ranges if the 
upper limit of the version given is greater the the max value of the version in the table.

```
Customdb.db :

create table packages(version varchar,name varchar);


insert into packages values('7.61.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.51.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.51.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.51.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.51.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.51.1',"libcurl");
insert into packages values('7.61.1',"libcurl");
```

Query:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Customdb.db')

c = conn.cursor()

software_name = "libcurl"
v1_start = "0.0.0"
v2_end_inc = "24.12.1"
v2_end_ex = "24.12.1"
only_version = '20.61.1'
print (type(v2_end_inc))

c.execute("""
        select name,version from packages
        where name = ?1 and
        1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000
        between
        (1000000 * replace(?2, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(?2, instr(?2, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(?2, '.', '000') % 1000)
        and
        (1000000 * replace(?3, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(?3, instr(?3, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(?3, '.', '000') % 1000)
        and
        (SELECT 1000000 * replace(?3, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(?3, instr(?3, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(?3, '.', '000') % 1000) >=
        (SELECT MAX(1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 ) FROM packages)
        ORDER BY
        (1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000)
    """, (software_name, v1_start, v2_end_inc))
```

Results:

```
libcurl|7.51.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.51.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.51.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.51.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.51.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.61.1                                                                                                                          
libcurl|7.61.1
```

If I download the file and decompress it and run the simple code it returns these results so there is nothing wrong with the downloading the remote file and decompressing it.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('primary.sqlite')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT version FROM packages where name = 'libcurl' ")

results = c.fetchall()

package_obj_list = []  
l = len(results)
for package in results:
   package_obj_list.append(package)

print (package_obj_list)

results are:

[ [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  “7.61.1” ], [  “7.61.1” ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  “7.61.1” ]]
```

However if I run the same code as that run on "primary.sqlite" file gives empty results.

```
software_name = "libcurl"
v1_start = "0.0.0"
v2_end_inc = "24.12.1"
v2_end_ex = "24.12.1"
only_version = '20.61.1'
print (type(v2_end_inc))

c.execute("""
        select name,version from packages
        where name = ?1 and
        1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000
        between
        (1000000 * replace(?2, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(?2, instr(?2, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(?2, '.', '000') % 1000)
        and
        (1000000 * replace(?3, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(?3, instr(?3, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(?3, '.', '000') % 1000)
        and
        (SELECT 1000000 * replace(?3, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(?3, instr(?3, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(?3, '.', '000') % 1000) >=
        (SELECT MAX(1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 ) FROM packages)
        ORDER BY
        (1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000)
    """, (software_name, v1_start, v2_end_inc))
```

Expected Results:

```
[ [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  “7.61.1” ], [  “7.61.1” ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  "7.55.1" ], [  “7.61.1” ]]
```

Current Results:

```
[]
```

Comment: You question is bit confusing, at the start of your question you say that remote sqlite file doesn't give result and in the end you say run on "Custom.db" file gives empty results is not giving the result. Can you simplify you question with somewhat summarised details.

Comment: @NishantPatel Thanks , I edited .

Answer (score 0):

The flaw is here:

```
>=
        (SELECT MAX(1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
        1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
        replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 ) FROM packages)
```

Expected results are returned  in the "customdb" test because there are only specific name/version rows.
Expected results are returned in the `SELECT version FROM packages where name = 'libcurl'` test on `primary.sqlite` because results are filtered by name.

BUT, since the above cited subquery does *not* filter by name, it is selecting the max "numberized" version for *all* rows in `packages`

Comment: You're welcome! If that's the answer, don't forget to accept it!